# Prove the convergence of $\{a_n\}$ with $0 \le a_{n+1}\le \frac{1}{2}(a_{n}+a_{n-1})$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Note that $a_{n+1}\le \frac{1}{2}(a_{n}+a_{n-1})\le \max(a_n,a_{n-1})$. Hence, if we define $b_n:=\max( a_{n},a_{n+1})$, then $b_{n+1}=\max(a_{n+1},a_{n+2})\le\max(a_{n+1},a_{n})=b_n, $ which implies $\{b_n\}$ is decreasing. Moreover, $ b_n\ge a_{n+1}\ge0,$ which implies $\{b_n\}$ is down-bounded. As per the the monotone bounded convergence theorem, $\{b_n\}$ is convergent.

But how to prove $\{a_n\}$ has the same limit as $\{b_n\}$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy They are not the same. Mine is more difficult than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already showed that $b_n=\max( a_{n},a_{n+1})$ is convergent. Now
$$
 b_{n+1} = \max(a_{n+1}, a_{n+2}) \le \max(a_{n+1}, \frac{a_n+a_{n+1}}{2}) \\
= \frac{a_{n+1}}{2} + \max(\frac{a_{n+1}}{2}, \frac{a_{n}}{2}) = \frac 12 (a_{n+1} + b_n)
$$
so that
$$
 2  b_{n+1} - b_n \le a_{n+1} \, .
$$
We also have $ b_n=\max( a_{n},a_{n+1}) \ge a_{n+1}$. So
$$
 2  b_{n+1} - b_n \le a_{n+1} \le b_n
$$
which shows that $(a_n)$ is convergent as well, with $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n$.

Comment: Good Solution！ THX.